# How to apply script on a tool part of a web part?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to apply Java-script on tool part of a web part in sharepoint in order to restrict a user from entering any character other than numerics. I've found a suitable script on [this link](https://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values/)

I can see on page source that script has been registered here, but I am really not sure what went wrong that script is not working here. I have tried to find out on fire bug, but it does not display any java-script errror. Please help me out knowing what silly mistake I might have made.

Following is my code on toolpart.cs

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    str.Append("$(document).ready(function() {$('#_txtHeight').keydown(function(event){");
    str.Append("if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {}else {");
    str.Append("if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {event.preventDefault();}}});});");
    str.Append("</script>");

    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyChartViewerToolPart" + this.ID, str.ToString());

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
    {
       this.Zone.ErrorText = string.Format(
           "{0}Changes cannot be saved due to one or more errors in input. {1}", 
           this.Zone.ErrorText, errorMessage);
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

_txtHeight is ID of my text box created in the method CreateChildControls() on the same page in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the jQuery selector with `$( "[id$='_txtHeight']" )` as asp.net 3.5 and earlier will add a prefix to the id. Alternatively if you want to use the id selector and you can access the control properties in `OnPreRender` you could use:

```
str.AppendFormat("$(document).ready(function() {{$('#{0}').keydown(function(event){{" control.ClientID);
```

Note when using `AppendFormat` curly braces must be escaped by doubling them up e.g. {{ and  }}